# Text at bottom of image

Tags: css, bulma

How to put the "Hello World!" text always to the right and bottom of the image?
Is it a pure CSS/flexbox solution, or Bulma itself offers a class to do that.
Also, should I use a `<p>` tag? Or another tag for that purpose? Because currently if you run the snippet (in full window), you see that the text is already to the right, but it's vertically centered and not at the bottom

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="level">
  <div class="level-left">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/256x256.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item justify-content-end">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use `margin-top:auto`

```css
.justify-content-end {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="level">
  <div class="level-left">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/256x256.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item justify-content-end">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your snippet different from OP's? Visually, the result is exactly the same... What am I missing?

Comment: @JeremyThille check full screen ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about `align-self: flex-end`, in order to stick with Flex properties?

```css
.justify-content-end {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="level">
  <div class="level-left">
    <div class="level-item">
      <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/256x256.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item justify-content-end">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```